# I am trying to get the locality name from the Json output to a string and pass it to a variable

Tags: android, api, geocoding, reverse, using

I am trying to fetch the locality name from the following json

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.486096,73.802027&sensor=false particular address which returs JSON. I m developing a android app to reverse geocode using api.

This is the code below ..

```
public class MyGeocoder 
{
public static String getUserLocation(Location loc) {

    String userlocation = null;
    String readUserFeed = readUserLocationFeed((Double.toString(loc.getLatitude())) +
    ","+( Double.toString(loc.getLongitude())));
    try {
        //JSONObject Strjson = new JSONObject(readUserFeed);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readUserFeed);
        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        userlocation = jsonObject.getString("locality").toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("User Location ", userlocation);
    return userlocation;
}

  public static String readUserLocationFeed(String address) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
    latlng="+ address + "&sensor=false");
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            //Log.e(ReverseGeocode.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For parsing json, you are doing it wrong. First of all url returns a `JSONObject` which contains a `JSONArray` "**result**" and a field "**status**".
So you should uncomment following line:

```
JSONObject Strjson = new JSONObject(readUserFeed);
```

And I recommend you to check the value of **status** field to see you it is OK and it has data like this:

```
if(Strjson.getString("status").equals("OK")) { ... }
```

Then get the `JSONArray` using:

```
JSONArray result = Strjson.getJSONArray("result");
```

and iterate through each `JSONObject` to get the field value you require, **BUT** the thing is json you are getting doesn't contain a field with name "locality" but contains it as a one of the values of type field.